# Javascript for of into for of duplicate value when i use array.push

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have a array with objects

**Object 1:**

```
var ips = [{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}, {"ip": "2.2.2.2"}]
```

**Object 2:**

```
var ports = [443, 80]
```

I would like to have the following:

```
var ipsAndPort = [
  {"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 443},
  {"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 80},
  {"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 443},
  {"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 80},

]
```

that's why I wrote this code :

```
var ipsAndPort = []
for (let obj of ips ) {                  
     for (let port of ports ) {
          let localob = obj
          localob["port"] = port
          ipsAndPort.push(localob)
      }                  
 }
```

but I get:

```
var ipsAndPort = [
  {"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 80},
  {"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 80},
  {"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 80},
  {"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 80},

]
```

however if i use console.log()

```
for (let obj of ips ) {                  
     for (let port of ports ) {
          let localob = obj
          localob["port"] = port
          console.log(localob)
      }                  
 }
```

I get the result that I hope

```
{"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 443}

{"ip": "1.1.1.1", "port": 80}

{"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 443}

{"ip": "2.2.2.2", "port": 80}
```

You can help understand why this happens.

Thank you

Comment: You are pushing a reference into you array. You will have to clone your objects before adding them to array.

Comment: `let localob = obj` it should be equal to a copy of `obj`, not `obj` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clone the Object instead of pushing a reference to it into the Array as each time the original Object is modified, the references in the Array will also be modified.

You can use `Object.assign({}, obj)` to create a copy of `obj`.

```js
var ips = [{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}, {"ip": "2.2.2.2"}]
var ports = [443, 80]
var ipsAndPort = []
for (let obj of ips ) {                  
     for (let port of ports ) {
          let localob = Object.assign({}, obj)
          localob["port"] = port
          ipsAndPort.push(localob)
      }                  
 }
 console.log(ipsAndPort);
```

A simpler way as suggested by Ori Drori:

```js
var ips = [{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}, {"ip": "2.2.2.2"}]
var ports = [443, 80]
var ipsAndPort = []
for (let obj of ips ) {                  
     for (let port of ports ) {
          ipsAndPort.push(Object.assign({port}, obj))
      }                  
 }
 console.log(ipsAndPort);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @hev1's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163806/5157454), another way to achieve the same result:

If you don't need to support IE/Edge, you can iterate the `ips` array with [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), and inside it use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to combine ports with the ips to new objects:

```js
const ips = [{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}, {"ip": "2.2.2.2"}]

const ports = [443, 80]

const result = ips.flatMap(o =>
  ports.map(port => ({ ...o, port }))
);

console.log(result);
```

If you need to IE/Edge, you can use two `Array.map()` calls, and flatten the results by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const ips = [{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}, {"ip": "2.2.2.2"}]

const ports = [443, 80]

const result = [].concat(...ips.map(o =>
  ports.map(port => ({ ...o, port }))
));

console.log(result);
```